# Transitioning from application index route to any other route won't trigger application-loading

Tags: ember.js

The first time i login into my application, it will transit to application index and from there I want to transit to my home route. The issue is that the application-loading and its corresponding template won't be triggered. I was wondering what i am missing here. I have noticed that if i am in my home route and i refresh the page, it will trigger application-loading substate.

Answer (score 0):

`return true` within your `index` route's `action.loading` function so that after that loading hook fires, the event will continue to bubble up to your application route.

Comment: I have added loading action in index route, it bubbles up to application route, but  still it doesnot show the application-loading template.